# Run issue with Lexikos AHKControl script?

Tags: windows-10, git, autohotkey

I've been looking for this script, AHKControl by lexikos all over the place. The original release [thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/26153-ahkcontrol/) is on the old defunct forum, that may be why I cant see any download links there.

I found a github page [here](https://github.com/Drugoy/Autohotkey-scripts-.ahk/blob/master/ScriptManager.ahk/AHKControl.ahk), that has a copy of the script but its missing a function or an include so it stops me from running it. It throws this error.

> C:\Users....AHKcontrol.ahk (97) : ==> Call to nonexistent function.
>   Specifically: MI_ExtractIcon(this_exe, 3, 16)

Propably because of missing #include files, Lexikos mentions this on the same release thread.

> Required: ListIncludes.ahk (placed in function library) Menu Icons v2
>   AutoHotkey v1.0 or v1.1 ANSI/Unicode 32-bit. 64-bit is not supported.

Does anyone have working copy of this file they can share with me?
If not can you please take a look at the github mirror, to see if you can resolve the error stoping it? I think its missing an icon pack. I am okay in AHK but not great. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can find it in [Ixiko's collections of functions and libraries](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=49994).

Comment: Yes, found it in there,  Thanks again :D